# How to animate ripple effect from center position to full diameter

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create an image button effect using the ripple. I however want the ripple effect to start from the center of my image button icon and fill the image button. Is it possible to have the ripple effect animate from center to full circle. Like a white circle animates in size from 0 to the diameter of the circle?

Comment: The Ripple effect, is a ripple so is not permanent, is like a wave. Do you want the animation to change the color permanently after it fills the circle?

Comment: No, not permanent, just like a click effect of taking a receipt picture.

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated in the documentation for the [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable) you can set the anchoring point using [setHotspot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable#setHotspot(float,%20float)) method.

By default `View` [sets the hotspot](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java;l=12286) to the current touch coordinates when pressed:

```
private void setPressed(boolean pressed, float x, float y) {
        if (pressed) {
            drawableHotspotChanged(x, y);
        }

        setPressed(pressed);
    }
```

And `ImageView` [passes](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java;l=1368) this hotspot to its content:

```
 public void drawableHotspotChanged(float x, float y) {
    super.drawableHotspotChanged(x, y);

    if (mDrawable != null) {
        mDrawable.setHotspot(x, y);
    }
}
```

So one way of getting the ripple effect starting from center is to extend `ImageView` and always set the hotspot to the center. There are other ways of course, e.g. one can try to extend `RippleDrawable` and override `setHotspot` there.

Comment: I am kind of stuck on how I can do this on Kotlin. Any blog examples